# TemplateView's get method: object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: django, django-views, django-testing, django-tests

There will be several tests: anonymous user from some pages will be redirected to login page. That's why some helper method was organized.
Now it is TemplateView, then it will be ListView etc.

When I try to transmit a request to the get method of TemplateView subclass, I get this error message: 'HomePageView' object has no attribute 'request'. But the signature of TemplateView's get method is def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs).

Could you give me a kick here?

**/photoarchive/general/views.py**

```
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "general/home.html"
```

**/photoarchive/general/tests.py**

```
class GeneralTest(TestCase):

    def test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(self, view_instance):
        user = User(username='anonymous', email='vvv@mail.ru', password='ttrrttrr')
        user.is_active = False        
        request = HttpRequest()
        request.user = user
        pdb.set_trace()
        response = view_instance.get(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
        self.assertEqual(response['location'], '/accounts/login/')

    def test_anonymous_user_from_home_page_redirected_to_login_page(self):
        view_instance = HomePageView()
        self.test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(view_instance)
```

**Traceback:**

```
ERROR: test_anonymous_user_from_home_page_redirected_to_login_page (general.tests.GeneralTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/workspace/photoarchive/photoarchive/general/tests.py", line 49, in test_anonymous_user_from_home_page_redirected_to_login_page
    self.test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page(view_instance)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/photoarchive/photoarchive/general/tests.py", line 23, in test_anonymous_user_redirected_to_login_page
    response = view_instance.get(request)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 158, in get
    return self.render_to_response(context)
  File "/home/michael/workspace/venvs/photoarchive/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 131, in render_to_response
    request=self.request,
AttributeError: 'HomePageView' object has no attribute 'request'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.028s
```

Interactive playing at pdb breakpoint:

```
-> response = view_instance.get(request)
(Pdb) view_instance
<general.views.HomePageView object at 0x7f9270d550f0>
(Pdb) request
<HttpRequest>
(Pdb) view_instance.get(request)
*** AttributeError: 'HomePageView' object has no attribute 'request'
(Pdb)
```

**For reference:**

```
class TemplateView(TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin, View):
    """
    A view that renders a template.  This view will also pass into the context
    any keyword arguments passed by the URLconf.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Testing individual CBV methods is tricky. You aren't meant to instantiate the view with `HomePageView()`.

In your `urls.py`, you do:

```
url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view()),
```

Similarly, in your test, you can do `HomePageView.as_view()`. This returns the callable view which you can pass the request to.

```
view_instance = HomePageView.as_view()
response = view_instance(request)
```